# How can I achieve to not only read one line from the txt file but also all the lines?

Tags: c#, authentication, split, text-files, streamreader

Im a beginner programmer. I started to learn c# about two weeks ago, and now I'm programming a simple Login/Register program but it's a bit hard for me. My question is: there is this 
`adat1= olvas.ReadLine();` code, and I think this is for read only one line from the txt. How can I achieve to read all the lines and then select the UserName which we write into the Console? After the solution we will be able to create new Users.
Thank you guys for your help!

My source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace Gyak
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool helyes = false;
            do {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("1 = Login\n2 = Registration");
            int valasz = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (valasz == 1)
            {
                StreamReader olvas = new StreamReader(@"D:\k\Gyakorlás 2\UserName.txt", Encoding.Default);
                while (!olvas.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string adat1;
                    helyes = true;
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Login");
                    Console.WriteLine("UserName: ");
                    Console.Write("Password: ");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 1);
                    string valasz1 = Console.ReadLine();
                    adat1 = olvas.ReadLine();
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 2);
                    string valasz2 = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (adat1.StartsWith(valasz1))
                    {
                        string[] keresett_adat = adat1.Split(':');
                        string keresett_eredmény = keresett_adat[1];
                        if (valasz2 == keresett_eredmény)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Login Succeeded");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Access Denied!\nTry again!");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
                }

                        else if (valasz == 2)
            {
                StreamWriter iras = new StreamWriter(@"D:\k\Gyakorlás 2\UserName.txt", true, Encoding.Default);
                helyes = true;
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Registration");
                Console.WriteLine("UserName: ");
                Console.Write("Password: ");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 1);
                string valasz3 = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 2);
                string valasz4 = Console.ReadLine();
                iras.WriteLine( "\n" + valasz3 + ":" + valasz4);
                iras.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                helyes = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect!");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
            }while(helyes != true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [File.ReadAllLines Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8) may be of interest.  Likewise other methods in the [File Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.8).  With all of them (pre) loaded it will be faster to loop thru them

Answer (score 0):

You can use `File.ReadAllText` or [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8).